# Environment variable appears after restart

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, environment-variables

After restarting my Windows 10 computer, an environment variable appears in my powershell session. This variable is not defined in any startup scripts, or in the environment variables under control panel. The command that I have been using to remove it is the following:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("TestVariable",$null,"Process")
```

However, this command only removes the environment variable until the next restart. How can I permanently remove this environment variable?

Comment: Have you looked in your PowerShell startup script?

Comment: If you're talking about `Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`, that script doesn't set any environment variables on startup.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was referring to.

Comment: Try to find out whether it is a variable set by PowerShell, in `cmd.exe` use `set` or start a PowerShell without profiles `Powershell.exe -noprofile`

Comment: Start with `-noprofile`.

Comment: The variable is there when I start a command prompt also. It doesn't seem to be confined to powershell.

Comment: Is your computer a part of a domain? Absolutely nothing setting this as a result of a startup script?